# Can SqlWorkspaceFactory connection files be created with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, arcgis-10.1

With ArcObjects, I can use `IWorkspaceFactory.Create` I can create a connection file for a SqlWorkspaceFactory.

Is there an out-of-the-box method to create the same file in ArcGIS Desktop?

**Update:** I tried the Create SDE Connection GP tool approach.  I am unable to Open with the OpenFromFile method.  The files are the same length but different when compared.
[image]

**Update 2:**  I experience the same result in ArcGIS 10.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally worked through this issue with Esri Support.

The answer is No, there doesn't exist an out-of-the-box way to create  connection files for SQL Workspaces.

The suggested workaround is to create and use the SDE workspace file, as in [Jason](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/391/jason-scheirer)'s [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/75490/31), and updating ArcObject code to read the connection properties off the SDE Workspace and opening the SQL Workspace with those connection properties (as opposed from opening directly from a connection file).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the [Create SDE Connection GP tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000pt000000).

Comment: I tried this and the `SqlWorkspaceFactory.OpenFromFile` fails. The files look to be the same size but different for a compare.